What's the SOTA sub-50MB model for machine translation on texts between 1 and 5 words?
What's the SOTA sub-50MB model for machine translation on texts between 1 and 5 words?
I am interested in translating the following languages (esp. languages marked by an asterisk) into English:

Danish

Dutch (Netherlands)

French*

German*

Italian*

Japanese*

Korean*

Norwegian

Portuguese (Brazil and EU)*

Russian*

Simplified Mandarin (China, Singapore)*

Spanish*

Swedish

Traditional Cantonese (Hong Kong)

Traditional Mandarin (Taiwan)



https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-translations-models has some pretty strong models(at least, from French, tested myself) which weight around 20 MB from ~20 languages to English (~20 MB per language).

Playground website: https://mozilla.github.io/translate
Training script: https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-translations-training
Firefox extension to use the models: https://browser.mt/
MPL-2.0 license
The models are based on https://marian-nmt.github.io/
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2022/06/training-efficient-neural-network-models-for-firefox-translations/ explains the training process:




Model
Size
Total number of parameters
Dataset decoding time on 1 CPU core
Quality, BLEU




Teacher
798Mb
192.75M
631s
52.5


Student quantized
17Mb
15.7M
17.9s
50.7




Firefox extension:

